# Ordenar objetos em arquivo json (Java)

Tags: java, json, classificação, gson

Tenho o seguinte arquivo JSON:

```
{"idAluno":1,"nomeAluno":"Teste","listaDeTurmas":[1,2,3,4]}
{"idAluno":4,"nomeAluno":"Teste","listaDeTurmas":[1,2,3,4]}
{"idAluno":3,"nomeAluno":"Teste","listaDeTurmas":[1,2,3,4]}
{"idAluno":5,"nomeAluno":"Teste","listaDeTurmas":[1,2,3,4]}
{"idAluno":2,"nomeAluno":"Teste","listaDeTurmas":[1,3,4]}
```

Estou utilizando a biblioteca Gson em Java. É possível ordenar estes registros de forma crescente no arquivo com base no campo "idAluno"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

Basta que tua classe utilize a interface [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). Nessa interface, tu definirás os critérios de comparação.

Então, tu podes adicionar teus elementos à uma [coleção que suporta ordenação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html), e usar o método `Collections.sort(testList);` ou `Collections.reverse(testList);`, dependendo da ordem desejada. Exemplo - `Collections.sort(testList, (a, b) -> b.compareTo(a));`

Comment: Sim, mas eu teria que deserializar a string Json para um objeto e usar, por exemplo, um ArrayList para fazer a ordenação, certo? Não há como fazer essa ordenação direto no arquivo json, sem precisar deserializar a string?

Comment: Aí não dá... Tu precisas deserializar para fazer qualquer coisa com os dados.

Comment: Certo. Obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Segue um exemplo onde foi necessario ordernar o json pelo atributo de valor booleano.

Detalhes do comando

```
parkingPlaces = lista de estacionamentos.
.stream().sorted = criar strem e comando de ordenacao
ParkingPlacesResponse.ParkingPlace = classe de objeto.
::getCloser = valor booleano que estou a ordenar.
.reversed() = sem ele o False fica no topo da lista.
.collect(Collectors.toList()) = finaliza a ordenacao inserindo em uma nova lista
```

Para JAVA 8+

Resultado:

```
parkingPlaces.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(ParkingPlacesResponse.ParkingPlace::getCloser).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```